# C, инициализируются ли нулем локальные статические переменные?

Tags: c, static

```
int f(void)
{
    static int i;// 

    // ...
}
```

Равноценно ли `static int i = 0;`?

PS. Я поправил описание вопроса, чтобы он относился конкретно к `C`, поскольку возникает путаница.

Comment: нет, локальные инициализируется тем, что есть в этой области памяти, это может быть и ноль и мусор.  Это не локальный, а статический

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, никак не могу найти в стандарте параграф, где бы это описывалось.

Comment: MGNeo, в стандарте не нужно искать, это есть в учебниках

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, В учебниках регулярно встречаются опечатки и описки. Как назло, в самых важных местах.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В С++ стандарт гласит:

> 6.6.2.1. Variables with static storage duration are initialized as a consequence of program initiation.
>
> 6.6.2.2. If constant initialization is not performed, a variable with static storage duration (6.7.1) or thread storage duration (6.7.2)
> is zero-initialized (11.6).

Т.е. такие переменные действительно инициализируются нулем (или конструктором по умолчанию).

Для С у меня нет стандарта, но есть "Язык С. Справочник". Там написано примерно то же самое, что

> объекты, имеющие статическую продолжительность хранения, неявно инициализируются нулевым значением по умолчанию, если только их определение не включает явный инициализатор.

Поскольку выяснилось, что проблема в переводе Прата, добавлю здесь подтверждение из оригинала книги:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сомнений мне добавила имеющаяся опечатка в книге **Язык программирования C, Стивен Прата, 6 издание**. На 492 странице написано: `Статические переменные инициализируются нулем, если они были явно инициализированы другим значением.` Долго пытался понять, что это значит, прежде чем понял, что к чему.

Comment: @MGNeo Думаю, что там должно быть "не были явно инициализированы". Отправьте замечание в издательство, там сравнят с оригиналом и скажут, не ошибка ли это переводчика :)

Comment: я так и сделаю.

Comment: Дайте ISBN или хотя бы название на английском (на титульном листе обычно есть титул оригинала), попробую поискать оригинал.

Comment: ISBN 978-5-8459-1950-2

Comment: См. дополненный ответ :) Так что можете смело писать в издательство...

Comment: спасибо за столь развернутую помощь. В издательство уже написал.

Answer (score 2):

Инициализация переменных со статическим временем хранения проходит в две стадии. Сначала при запуске программы происходит статическая инициализация, инициализирующая переменную либо известным константным значением, либо нулем. А только потом динамическая инициализация, если она требуется (для локальных статических переменных она происходит при первом прохождении через соответствующее объявление, это описывается в 9.7.4, в С она отсутствует). В вашем примере `i` гарантировано инициализируется нулем.

> **6.6.2 Static initialization [basic.start.static]**
>   1 Variables with static storage duration are initialized as a consequence of program initiation...
>   2 A constant initializer for a variable or temporary object o is an initializer whose full-expression is a constant expression, except that if o is an object, such an initializer may also invoke constexpr constructors for o and its subobjects even if those objects are of non-literal class types. [Note: Such a class may have a non-trivial destructor. —end note ] Constant initialization is performed if a variable or temporary object with static or thread storage duration is initialized by a constant initializer for the entity. If constant initialization is not performed, a variable with static storage duration (6.7.1) or thread storage duration (6.7.2) is zero-initialized (11.6). Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization. All static initialization strongly happens before (4.7.1) any dynamic initialization.

Comment: Еще стоит отметить, что `static int i = rand();` запрещено, поскольку инициализация переменной выполняется в момент запуска программы, и такая инициализация требует константного выражения. По крайней мере, это справедливо для `C`.

Comment: @MGNeo В С просто отсутствует стадия динамической инициализации.